# Trouble Understanding Dominant Strategy in the Prisoners Dilemma

Tags: game-theory

Here's a payoff matrix for a Prisoners Dilemma:

[image]

Alpha is supposed to be the dominant strategy, which means that "no matter what my pair chooses, I will be better off playing Alpha than playing Beta."

I'm having trouble understanding this, because if my pair plays Beta, I'm better off playing Beta than Alpha.

My question is: "Why is Alpha the dominant strategy?"
(or "Why is defecting the dominant strategy in the prisoners dilemma?")

Comment: I just noticed that this matrix doesn't follow the T>R>P>S criteria of the Prisoners Dilemma. Here it seems that R<P. 
But in this lecture, the teacher says that Alpha is the dominant strategy! So the question remains... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM3rTU927io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if my pair plays Beta, I'm better off playing Beta than Alpha.

In case of $(\beta,\beta)$, you get 1, but in case of $(\alpha,\beta)$, meaning you play $\alpha$ against pair's $\beta$, you get 3, and $$3>1.$$

Comment: Oh lort, I misspoke. Let's see... if I play  and my pair plays , I get 0. But if I play  and my pair plays , I get 1. That makes me think that playing  can be better than , so  can't be a strictly dominating strategy.

Comment: No matter what fixed strategy your partner plays, you are better off playing $\alpha$. This is all that the definition is. It does not say anything about what happens if both of you change strategies.

Comment: Ahh I get it, I wasn't looking at pair's strategy as having to be fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Going by the definition of dominant strategy from [here](https://web.mit.edu/14.12/www/02F_lecture3-602.pdf):

A strategy $s_i^∗$ strictly dominates $s_i$ iff $u_i(s^∗_i , s_{−i}) > u_i(s_i, s_{−i})$, $∀s_{−i} \in S_{−i}$.

Here we have $S_{-me}=\{\alpha, \beta\}$ and $s_{me} \in \{\alpha, \beta\} = S_{me}$, with

$u_{me}(\alpha, \alpha) = 0 > -1 = u_{me}(\beta, \alpha)$,

$u_{me}(\alpha, \beta) = 3 > 1 = u_{me}(\beta, \beta)$

Combining the above two,

$u_{me}(\alpha , s_{−me}) > u_{me}(s_{me}, s_{−me})$, $∀s_{−me} \in S_{−me}$ and $s_{me} \in S_{me} - \{\alpha\}$

$\implies s^∗_{me} = \alpha$, i.e., $\alpha$ is the dominant strategy for me.